# Array of objects on Vue method

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js

I have an object of type "Sorteio" and inside it a vector of objects of type "Resultado", specifically 6 Resultados. I'm instantiating them this way:

```
saveSorteio() {
      var data = {
        loteria: this.sorteio.loteria,
        resultados: [
          {
            valor: this.sorteio.resultados[0].valor,
            animal: this.sorteio.resultados[0].animal
          },
          {
            valor: this.sorteio.resultados[1].valor,
            animal: this.sorteio.resultados[1].animal
          },
          /* ... */
        ]
      };
}
```

Is there another way to instantiate the 6 at once or do I need to keep calling index by index?

Comment: try to make a  loop through that array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`#array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to make an array that pulls out these properties:

```
saveSorteio() {
    var data = {
      loteria: this.sorteio.loteria,
      resultados = this.sorteio.resultados.map(({valor, animal}) => ({valor, animal}))

        /* ... */

    };
}
```

For example:

```js
sorteio = {
    resultados: [
        {valor: "v1", animal: 'a1', somethingelse:"else"},
        {valor: "v2", animal: 'a2', somethingelse:"else"},
        {valor: "v3", animal: 'a3', somethingelse:"else"}
    ]
}
let newArray = sorteio.resultados.map(({valor, animal}) => ({valor, animal}))
console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer I was looking for.